# SQL Server : grouping and combining columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
--Create/Populate [#Feedback]:
if object_id('tempdb..[#Feedback]','U') is not null 
    drop table [#Feedback]
go

create table [#Feedback]
(
     [feedbackid] int,
     [feedbackgroup] varchar(50),
     [feedbackdatetime] datetime,
     [feedbackresult] varchar(max),
     [feedbackdataelement] varchar(50)
)
go

set nocount on
insert [#Feedback] select 1, 'A001', '2018-08-24 08:00:00', 'true', 'ArrivedLate'
insert [#Feedback] select 2, 'A001', '2018-08-24 08:00:00', 'false', 'LeftEarly'
insert [#Feedback] select 3, 'A001', '2018-08-24 08:00:00', 'false', 'Unprepared'
insert [#Feedback] select 4, 'A001', '2018-08-24 08:00:00', 'Arrived 5 minutes late', 'Comments'
insert [#Feedback] select 5, 'A056', '2018-08-24 09:14:00', 'false', 'ArrivedLate'
insert [#Feedback] select 6, 'A056', '2018-08-24 09:14:00', 'false', 'LeftEarly'
insert [#Feedback] select 7, 'A056', '2018-08-24 09:14:00', 'true', 'Unprepared'
insert [#Feedback] select 8, 'A056', '2018-08-24 09:14:00', 'Did not bring laptop', 'Comments'
insert [#Feedback] select 9, 'B251', '2018-08-24 12:28:00', 'true', 'ArrivedLate'
insert [#Feedback] select 10, 'B251', '2018-08-24 12:28:00', 'true', 'Left Early'
insert [#Feedback] select 11, 'B251', '2018-08-24 12:28:00', 'true', 'Unprepared'
insert [#Feedback] select 12, 'B251', '2018-08-24 12:28:00', 'Showed up an hour late and had not showered, left at noon', 'Comments'
go
select * from [#Feedback]
```

I'm working with a table that looks like this. I am trying to format the data a little differently.

Ideally, this is what I'd like the output to be.

```
Group   DateTime            Feedback                                Comments
A001    2018-08-24 08:00:00 Arrived Late                            Arrived 5 minutes late
A056    2018-08-24 09:14:00 Unprepared                              Did not bring laptop
B251    2018-08-24 12:28:00 Arrived Late, Left Early, Unprepared    Showed up an hour late and had not showered, left at noon
```

I'm not sure how to do this.  I need to group all of the feedbackgroup IDs together, then I need to check if  feedbackresult is true and, if it is, list this in a column.  If there's more than one that is true, I need to list each of them in the single column.  Finally, I need to put the Comments in their own column.

Ideally I'd also like the new "Feedback" column to have some better formatted wording (Arrived Late instead of ArrivedLate).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server (starting with 2017) then you can give a try with [STRING_AGG](http://STRING_AGG).

Otherwise try this. If multiple comments are allowed for one ID, then you need to change Comments column accordingly (like Feedback column). I ignored word formatting since it is really obscure.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  f1.[feedbackgroup] as Group, 
  max([feedbackdatetime]) as Datetime,
  Stuff((SELECT ', ' + f2.[feedbackdataelement] 
       FROM [#feedback] AS f2 
       WHERE (f2.[feedbackresult] = 'true' AND f2.[feedbackgroup] = f1.[feedbackgroup]) 
       FOR xml path(''), type).value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') 
  AS Feedback, 
  (SELECT [feedbackresult] FROM [#feedback] AS f3 
   WHERE  f3.[feedbackdataelement] = 'Comments' AND f3.feedbackgroup = f1.feedbackgroup) 
   AS Comments 
FROM   [#feedback] AS f1 
GROUP  BY f1.[feedbackgroup]
```

Answer (score 2):

Basiacally you want `CASE`s returning a non empty or empty string depending on the values of `[feedbackdataelement]` and possibly `[feedbackresult]` in `max()`s and a `GROUP BY [feedbackgroup]`.

```
SELECT [feedbackgroup] [group],
       max([feedbackdatetime]) [datetime],
       stuff(concat(max(CASE
                          WHEN [feedbackdataelement] = 'ArrivedLate'
                               AND [feedbackresult] = 'true' THEN
                            ', Arrived Late'
                          ELSE
                            ''
                        END),
                    max(CASE
                          WHEN [feedbackdataelement] = 'LeftEarly'
                               AND [feedbackresult] = 'true' THEN
                            ', Left Early'
                          ELSE
                            ''
                        END),
                    max(CASE
                          WHEN [feedbackdataelement] = 'Unprepared'
                               AND [feedbackresult] = 'true' THEN
                            ', Unprepared'
                          ELSE
                            ''
                        END)),
             1,
             2,
             '') [feedback],
       max(CASE [feedbackdataelement]
             WHEN 'Comments' THEN
               [feedbackresult]
             ELSE
               ''
           END) [comments]
       FROM [feedback]
       GROUP BY [feedbackgroup];
```